# How do I call go-code with a cmd command in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a `.go` code that I want to run and get the return value in PHP.

The line I use in CMD is "go run test.go map.csv" and I want to run it through a PHP script and get whatever the code returns on my website.

Right now I don't get anything to my variable in the PHP-code.

GO-code

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math/bits"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const MaxInt = int(^uint(0) >> 1)

// IntSet

type IntSet struct {
    Storage uint
}

func (vs IntSet) Contains(value int) bool {
    return (vs.Storage & (1 << uint(value))) != 0
}

func (vs IntSet) Count() int {
    return bits.OnesCount(vs.Storage)
}

func (vs *IntSet) Insert(value int) {
    vs.Storage |= 1 << uint(value)
}

func (vs *IntSet) Remove(value int) {
    vs.Storage &= ^(1 << uint(value))
}

func (vs IntSet) Value() int {
    return int(vs.Storage >> 1)
}

func (vs IntSet) Iter() []int {
    n := vs.Count()
    v := make([]int, n)
    for c, i := 0, 0; c < n; i++ {
        if vs.Contains(i) {
            v[c] = i
            c++
        }
    }
    return v
}

func (vs IntSet) String() string {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.WriteString("{")
    delim := ""
    for c, i := 0, 0; c < vs.Count(); i++ {
        if vs.Contains(i) {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s%v", delim, i))
            delim = ","
            c++
        }
    }
    buf.WriteString("}")
    return buf.String()
}

// Combinations 'k' integers from a serie '1..n'

type Combs []IntSet

func combWithLen(n, k, first int, vs IntSet, acc Combs) Combs {
    if k > vs.Count() {
        for x := first; x <= n; x++ {
            s := vs
            s.Insert(x)
            acc = combWithLen(n, k, x+1, s, acc)
        }
    } else {
        acc = append(acc, vs)
    }
    return acc
}

func Comb(n, k int) Combs {
    return combWithLen(n, k, 1, IntSet{}, Combs{})
}

// Held Karp

type Path struct {
    Cost int
    From int
}

func minPath(paths []Path) Path {
    m := paths[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(paths); i++ {
        if m.Cost > paths[i].Cost {
            m = paths[i]
        }
    }
    return m
}

func pathFromTo(from, to int, c [][]Path, dists CostMatrix, prev IntSet) Path {
    p := Path{}
    p.Cost = c[prev.Value()][from-1].Cost + dists[from][to]
    p.From = from
    return p
}

func reverse(a []int) []int {
    for i, j := 0, len(a)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    }
    return a
}

// CostMatrix

type CostMatrix [][]int

func (dists CostMatrix) CalcCostToSubsets(c [][]Path, edges, subsetSz int) {
    maxWorkers := runtime.NumCPU()
    workers := 0
    done := make(chan bool)
    for _, visited := range Comb(edges, subsetSz) {
        if workers == maxWorkers {
            <-done
        } else {
            workers += 1
        }
        go func(vs IntSet) {
            subset := vs.Iter()
            // Find the lowest cost to get to this subset
            for _, k := range subset {
                prev := vs
                prev.Remove(k)
                res := []Path{}
                for _, m := range subset {
                    if m != k {
                        res = append(res, pathFromTo(m, k, c, dists, prev))
                    }
                }
                if len(res) > 0 {
                    c[vs.Value()][k-1] = minPath(res)
                }
            }
            done <- true
        }(visited)
    }
    // Wait for all workers to finish
    for ; workers > 0; workers -= 1 {
        <-done
    }
}

func (dists CostMatrix) ShortestPath() (int, []int) {
    n := len(dists)
    c := make([][]Path, 1<<uint(n-1))
    for i := 0; i < len(c); i++ {
        c[i] = make([]Path, n-1)
    }
    // Add paths from start to first steps
    for k := 1; k < n; k++ {
        c[1<<uint(k-1)][k-1] = Path{dists[0][k], 0}
    }
    for s := 2; s < n; s++ {
        dists.CalcCostToSubsets(c, n-1, s)
    }
    visited := IntSet{}
    for k := 1; k < n; k++ {
        visited.Insert(k)
    }
    // Add path back to start and calculate optimal cost
    res := []Path{}
    for k := 1; k < n; k++ {
        res = append(res, pathFromTo(k, 0, c, dists, visited))
    }
    p := minPath(res)
    cost := p.Cost
    // Backtrack to find path
    steps := make([]int, n+1)
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        steps[i] = p.From
        from := p.From
        p = c[visited.Value()][p.From-1]
        visited.Remove(from)
    }
    return cost, reverse(steps)
}

func (c CostMatrix) MaxDigitWidth() (width int) {
    for row := 0; row < len(c); row++ {
        for col := 0; col < len(c[row]); col++ {
            w := 0
            for d := c[row][col]; d > 0; d /= 10 {
                w += 1
            }
            if width < w {
                width = w
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

func (c CostMatrix) String() string {
    fmtstr := fmt.Sprintf("%%%vv", c.MaxDigitWidth())
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    for row := 0; row < len(c); row++ {
        if row == 0 {
            buf.WriteString("{\n")
        }
        buf.WriteString("    { ")
        for col := 0; col < len(c[row]); col++ {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf(fmtstr, c[row][col]))
            if col != len(c[row])-1 {
                buf.WriteString(", ")
            }
        }
        buf.WriteString(" },\n")
        if row == len(c)-1 {
            buf.WriteString("}")
        } else {
        }
    }
    return buf.String()
}

func Abs(n int) int {
    if n < 0 {
        return -n
    }
    return n
}

func Max(a, b int) int {
    if a < b {
        return b
    }
    return a
}

type Location struct {
    shelf int
    level int
}

func cost(from, to Location) int {
    dx := Abs(from.shelf - to.shelf)
    dy := Abs(from.level-to.level) * 2
    return Max(dx, dy)
}

func zeroMatrix(dim int) CostMatrix {
    var c CostMatrix = make([][]int, dim)
    for i := range c {
        c[i] = make([]int, dim)
    }
    return c
}

func genMatrix(nodes, depth, height int) CostMatrix {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    c := zeroMatrix(nodes)
    l := make([]Location, nodes)
    for i := range l {
        l[i] = Location{rand.Intn(depth), rand.Intn(height)}
    }
    for row := 0; row < nodes; row++ {
        for col := row + 1; col < nodes; col++ {
            c[row][col] = cost(l[row], l[col])
            c[col][row] = c[row][col]
        }
    }
    return c
}

func readMatrix(r io.Reader) CostMatrix {
    cr := csv.NewReader(r)
    rec, err := cr.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    M := zeroMatrix(len(rec))
    for row, line := range rec {
        for col, str := range line {
            v, err := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimSpace(str), 10, 32)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
            M[row][col] = int(v)
        }
    }

    return M
}

func GetCostMatrix() CostMatrix {
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        return readMatrix(os.Stdin)
    }
    arg := os.Args[1]
    if strings.HasSuffix(arg, ".csv") {
        file, err := os.Open(arg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        return readMatrix(file)
    }
    dim, err := strconv.ParseInt(arg, 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return genMatrix(int(dim), 50, 9)
}

// Program entrypoint

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)

    c := GetCostMatrix()
    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(c.ShortestPath())

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Processen tog %s sekunder", elapsed)
}
```

I want to catch what the GO-code main() returns in PHP:

```
<?php
$cmdOutput = exec('go run c:/Go/src/hello/test.go c:/Go/src/hello/map.csv');
var_dump($cmdOutput);
?>
```

but it says $cmdOutput is 0.

Comment: take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php

Comment: shell_exec, exec, system... checked them all but I get nothing returned when I run those functions.

Comment: Try Symfony's [Process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). With that you can output in the go script to the buffer and your Process returns it in `$process->getOutput()`. There's also a way to do an [output buffering approach](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output) if the csv is large, or [asynchronously](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously). Or you could write the CSV rows to another filename/format you pass the go script (json?) and don't fool with output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/go/bin/go /path/to/test.go map.csv 2>&1';
exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
```

just make sure your web server user has permissions (e.g www-data).

Comment: I tried but it gives me 0 in return. I updated my code above, I hope someone can solve it!

Comment: @RobinJakobsson I've updated the code to ignore shell output 2>&1 and have the result in the $output Array param, please try now

Comment: HOW DO I EDIT TEXT IN COMMENTS? Can't make rowbreaks or code tags! I've tried this:
`
<?php  
$output = [];  
$cmd = 'go run c:/Go/src/hello/test.go map.csv 2>&1';  
exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);  
var_dump($output);  
?>
`
  
And that gives me: array (size=2)
  0 => string ''go' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' (length=58)
  1 => string 'operable program or batch file.' (length=31)

Comment: Your code $cmd = '/usr/local/go/bin/go /path/to/test.go map.csv 2>&1'; doesnt work, I guess the go-command is not correct. I have a folder in User/Robin/go/bin/ with some go .exe files. dlv.exe, gocode-gomod.exe, goimports.exe, go-outline.exe, gopkgs.exe, gopls.exe and goreturns.exe

Comment: Solved it! Just wrote $cmd = 'C:/go/bin/go run c:/Go/src/hello/test.go map.csv 2>&1';

Answer (score 0):

To capture the output, you need to provide extra parameters.

```
$cmdOutput = []; // Variabled passed by reference.
exec('go run c:/Go/src/hello/test.go c:/Go/src/hello/map.csv', $cmdOutput);
var_dump($cmdOutput); // Will be an array of all printed lines.
```

[documentation exec function](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php)

Comment: `<?php
$output = [];
exec('go run c:/Go/src/hello/test.go c:/Go/src/hello/map.csv', $output);
var_dump($output);
?>`

gives me

`
C:\wamp64\www\hkgo.php:4:\n
array (size=0)
  empty
`

Comment: when you run `go run c:/Go/src/hello/test.go c:/Go/src/hello/map.csv` on your terminal, what is displayed ?

Comment: When I run it in cmd its giving me the programs output. The matrix, An optimal path and time consumed to run the program. But nothing when I call it with PHP.

Comment: please temporally replace your "go" call by "whoami", do the same on your cli. And check if webserver are running with the permission to execute your go program.